# Basis of Eigenvectors, Determining Invertible Matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Question is, from finding a basis of e-vectors, determine an invertible matrix **P** such that: [image]  is diagonal. (write down the matrix F)

[image]

For my e-values using:

[image]

I obtained [image]

Now for my e-vectors I'm slightly confused since I dont know what to do after plugging in [image] I got:

[image]

what do I do from here?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! I suppose the matrix in your post is $A$, not $L$?

Comment: @Bernard I have to say I agree with you, otherwise the question has given the invertible matrix... that would be handy :p

Comment: The answer by Rebellos is surely right; however, to me it always seem more handy to pick one of your coordinates zero to obtain your two eigenvectors. E.g., set $y=0$ to obtain $(-1,0,1)$, and set $y=0$ to obtain $(-2,1,0)$. You now also know that there is only one eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda=4$, and after you have found that one you are done.

Comment: @bernard, my mistake slight error i'll change it :)

Comment: @Reety updated post

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your mathematical formulas instead of pasting in images. The latter are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers, nor do they show up in question summaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Property you're talking about is a matrix being "diagonalizable". An $n\times n$  matrix is diagonalizable if and only if it has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. Since eigenvectors from distinct eigenvalues are always linearly independent, it is automatically diagonalizable if it has $n$ distinct eigenvalues. Yours only has two, which means that you have to find two linearly independent eigenvectors for one of them. You can find them by finding a basis for $Nul(L - \lambda I)$. After you have the eigenvectors, say $\{\mathbf{v_1,v_2}\}$ for $\lambda_1$ and $\mathbf{v_3}$ for $\lambda_2$, set

$$P = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{v_1} \ | \ \mathbf{v_2} \ | \ \mathbf{v_3} \end{bmatrix}$$

then $$P^{-1}LP = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda_2
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

EDIT-

In response to your comment. To find a basis for $Nul(L-\lambda I)$

You have $x + 2y + z = 0 \implies z = -x-2y$

So $\mathbf{Lx} = \mathbf{0}$ implies

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z 
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
-x-2y 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
0  \\
-x
\end{bmatrix} 
+
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
y\\
-2y
\end{bmatrix} 
=
x*
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
+ y *
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
-2
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

Takes those as your eigenvectors. Then do the same for $\lambda = 4$

Comment: what would be a suitable method for finding a basis for my Nul(L−λI)?

Comment: @Reety Sure. Let me find my calc. When I took linear alg we learned how to do it early on so I assumed you knew. I'll walk you through it

Comment: so for λ=4, I got x=z and 3x+2y+z=0, how would I do the Lx=0 part? would it be [z,-2z,z]?

Comment: @Reety yes, then factor out z to get [1,-2,1]. I actually wound up doing this yesterday on my calc and got the right answer. The two i posted above and the one you did on your own will work. Although (3x+2y+z) should read (2y+z)

Answer (score 0):

If your calculations are correct (which I'm not going to check), getting an equation like :

$$x+2y+z=0$$

means that your eigenvector could be any $v = [x|y|z]^T$, such that $x+2y+z=0$. Remember that such an expression defines a plane, so any vector that belongs in such a plane, is an eigenvector to your system. (**do not take $(0,0,0)$**)

It can easily be seen that for $x=1,y=-1,z=1$, the equation is satisfied, thus an eigenvector for your matrix is :

$$v=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

The eigenspace $E_2$ for the eigenvalue $2$ since it is defined by the single equation $x+2y+2$. Indeed you can define an isomorphism
\begin{align}
\varphi\colon\mathbf R^2&\longrightarrow E_2,\\
(x,y)&\longmapsto (x,y, -x-2y).
\end{align}
This isomorphism maps a basis of $\mathbf R^2$ onto a basis of $E_2$. In  particular,  the image of the canonical basis of $\mathbf R^2$:
$$\varphi(e_1)=(1,0,-1),\quad\varphi(e_21)=(0,1,-2)$$ 
is a basis of $E_2$.